# Recursive BEFORE UPDATE trigger in PostgreSQL don't use last returned new

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a table with before update trigger that can fire itself by update the same row, but result of update statement is not last value returned by that trigger. I do not understand why and how it works. The question is more understandable on example:

```
BEGIN;

SET client_min_messages = 'notice';

CREATE TABLE public.test (
  id INTEGER, 
  status INTEGER, 
  value numeric
);

CREATE SEQUENCE test_seq;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_tr() RETURNS trigger AS $body$
DECLARE
    seq integer;
BEGIN
    seq := nextval('test_seq');
    RAISE NOTICE 'Started: %', seq;
    IF new.status != old.status THEN
        UPDATE test SET value = new.value WHERE id = new.id;
    END IF;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Finished: %, RETURNED NEW: %', seq, new;
    RETURN new;
END
$body$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER test_tr BEFORE UPDATE ON test FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_tr();

INSERT INTO test (id, status, value) VALUES (1, 1, 1);

UPDATE test SET status = 2, value = 2 WHERE id = 1;

SELECT * FROM test;

ROLLBACK;
```

It is produce following:

```
NOTICE:  Started: 1
NOTICE:  Started: 2
NOTICE:  Finished: 2, RETURNED NEW: (1,1,2)
NOTICE:  Finished: 1, RETURNED NEW: (1,2,2)
UPDATE 0

 id | status | value 
----+--------+-------
  1 |      1 |     2
```

As you can see the last returned *new* is (1,2,2) (status = 2, value = 2), but last SELECT returns row with "status" = 1 and "value" = 2. Why status = "1"? Why not "2"?

Comment: You should be using a *statement level* trigger, not a row level trigger.

Answer (score 0):

The manual doesn't seem to define any specific behavior when a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger calls `UPDATE` on the same row.

Intuitively we might expect that the last value of `NEW` gets into the row, but as the result demonstrates, it's not what happens.

What I suggest is happening:

1. the trigger issues UPDATE #2. At this point the row still has its initial `(1,1,1)` 
   value.
2. the trigger starts again for UPDATE #2, but it just returns `NEW` so it doesn't change anything.
3. once the UPDATE #2 completes, a new version of the row becomes current with `(1,1,2)` as contents.
4. when UPDATE #1 completes, the engine should write in `NEW=(1,2,2)`, but then it notices that the version of the row it's working on has already been superseded. So it discards its `NEW` record and leaves it at that.

This is consistent with psql reporting `UPDATE 0`: the UPDATE #1 did not actually  update any row.